# Hosting dataservice in IIS or Local Services

Tags: wcf, iis, service, iis-7

Normally I host my WCF services in IIS but I've been told by a colleague that services run better (performance wise) when hosted in Local services.

Is this true? What are the pros and cons for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing how your services are designed, how much CPU/memory they consume, how many concurrent clients they support, how they are accessed, etc., it's hard to make a general statement about which method is better/faster. So I'll share my previous experience.

Initially we hosted our WCF services in local Windows Services, after doing some rudimentary performance testing against the two WCF deployment methods. Hosting them in Win Svcs was slightly faster (not noticeably). .NET 4.0/REST/wsHTTPBinding/total 3,000 conc. calls/load balanced sever farm/memory intensive/default WCF settings (initially didn't tweak them).

Then we noticed the memory on our WCF servers was maxing out several days after starting the service and when it happened our services generated strange exceptions sporadically. We turned on perf counters on our servers. That's when we learned that perf profiling WCF services hosted in Win Svc didn't give us a whole lot of insight because many perf counters simply didn't return any info at all, which was confirmed by Microsoft Tech Support team. We also used [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) to look for memory leaks but didn't find any major issue in our code. We then started tweaking WCF settings (e.g. maxbufferpoolsize) attentively with the help from Microsoft consultants. Ultimately we came to the conclusion that GC wasn't happening frequently enough to free up allocated memory. We even tried switching to [server mode GC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851764.aspx) from workstation mode, which actually ended up worsening the problem.

As the last resort, we switched to IIS. The performance of the service didn't get any better, which was fully expected. However, some of the IIS-specific perf counters confirmed our suspicion about GC not happening frequently enough. We then found this wonderful [setting](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling) in IIS that allowed us to [specify when and how often to recycle an app pool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753179%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). Yes, we could have developed a simple custom solution to restart our WCF services but why reinvent the wheel, we thought. Additionally, when you recycle an app pool in IIS, [IIS doesn't kill it abruptly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11089872/1580743). Instead, it creates a new one to handle subsequent requests while the old one stays a live for a configurable amount of time to finish processing all outstanding requests. That built-in capability allowed us to maintain our uptime SLA.

Based on my experience, I would suggest you keep them in IIS unless you really really really need to squeeze for that last bit of juice from your servers.

Comment: Thank you for your response I found it really useful and detailed :)